# Using Jquery each to parse Google Reader starred.json

Tags: jquery, json, google-reader

I am having trouble parsing the starred.json file from my google reader export to make it into an html file for import into getpocket

using jquery each I did not paste the content of starred.json here because it is too large

The problem is the mix of arrays and objects

I am trying to get the url, title and summary

```
    var data = {
  "id" : "user/17115776656148603551/state/com.google/starred",
  "title" : "Dasa סימן פריטים בכוכב ב-Google Reader",
  "author" : "Dasa",
  "updated" : 1368699933,
  "direction" : "ltr",
  "items" : [ {
    "crawlTimeMsec" : "1368699933957",
    "timestampUsec" : "1368699933957939",
    "id" : "tag:google.com,2005:reader/item/eb307953496c3755",
    "categories" : [ "user/17115776656148603551/state/com.google/starred", "user/17115776656148603551/state/com.google/fresh", "search", "job search", "news stories", "trending", "job hunting", "news", "vanity searches", "productivity", "search query", "google alerts", "alerts", "organization", "local news", "google", "time savers", "trending news", "shortcuts", "notifications" ],
    "title" : "Five Creative Uses for Google Alerts",
    "published" : 1366282800,
    "updated" : 1366282800,
    "canonical" : [ {
      "href" : "http://lifehacker.com/five-creative-uses-for-google-alerts-475278626"
    } ],
    "alternate" : [ {
      "href" : "http://feeds.gawker.com/~r/lifehacker/full/~3/jaLbxODg6SM/five-creative-uses-for-google-alerts-475278626",
      "type" : "text/html"
    } ],
    "summary" : {
      "direction" : "ltr",
      "content" : "<p><img height=\"360\" width=\"640\" src=\"http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/18kye9icys64djpg/ku-xlarge.jpg\"></p><p>Google Alerts is one of Google's hidden gems. It's a really powerful tool to keep track of trends, interesting topics, or anything really new that appears on the web. If you're not using it already, here are a few creative ways to get started with it.</p><p><a href=\"http://lifehacker.com/five-creative-uses-for-google-alerts-475278626\">Read more...</a></p><img width=\"1\" height=\"1\" src=\"http://lifehacker.feedsportal.com/c/34977/f/647165/s/2add7ec3/mf.gif\" border=\"0\"><div><table border=\"0\"><tr><td valign=\"middle\"><a href=\"http://share.feedsportal.com/share/twitter/?u=http%3A%2F%2Flifehacker.com%2Ffive-creative-uses-for-google-alerts-475278626&amp;t=Five+Creative+Uses+for+Google+Alerts\"><img src=\"http://res3.feedsportal.com/social/twitter.png\" border=\"0\"></a> <a href=\"http://share.feedsportal.com/share/facebook/?u=http%3A%2F%2Flifehacker.com%2Ffive-creative-uses-for-google-alerts-475278626&amp;t=Five+Creative+Uses+for+Google+Alerts\"><img src=\"http://res3.feedsportal.com/social/facebook.png\" border=\"0\"></a> <a href=\"http://share.feedsportal.com/share/linkedin/?u=http%3A%2F%2Flifehacker.com%2Ffive-creative-uses-for-google-alerts-475278626&amp;t=Five+Creative+Uses+for+Google+Alerts\"><img src=\"http://res3.feedsportal.com/social/linkedin.png\" border=\"0\"></a> <a href=\"http://share.feedsportal.com/share/gplus/?u=http%3A%2F%2Flifehacker.com%2Ffive-creative-uses-for-google-alerts-475278626&amp;t=Five+Creative+Uses+for+Google+Alerts\"><img src=\"http://res3.feedsportal.com/social/googleplus.png\" border=\"0\"></a> <a href=\"http://share.feedsportal.com/share/email/?u=http%3A%2F%2Flifehacker.com%2Ffive-creative-uses-for-google-alerts-475278626&amp;t=Five+Creative+Uses+for+Google+Alerts\"><img src=\"http://res3.feedsportal.com/social/email.png\" border=\"0\"></a></td></tr></table></div><br><br><a href=\"http://da.feedsportal.com/r/163644809562/u/49/f/647165/c/34977/s/2add7ec3/kg/342/a2.htm\"><img src=\"http://da.feedsportal.com/r/163644809562/u/49/f/647165/c/34977/s/2add7ec3/kg/342/a2.img\" border=\"0\"></a><img width=\"1\" height=\"1\" src=\"http://pi.feedsportal.com/r/163644809562/u/49/f/647165/c/34977/s/2add7ec3/kg/342/a2t.img\" border=\"0\"><img src=\"http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/lifehacker/full/~4/jaLbxODg6SM\" height=\"1\" width=\"1\">"
    },
    "author" : "Alan Henry",
    "comments" : [ ],
    "annotations" : [ ],
    "origin" : {
      "streamId" : "feed/http://lifehacker.com/index.xml",
      "title" : "Lifehacker",
      "htmlUrl" : "http://lifehacker.com"
    }
  }, {
    "crawlTimeMsec" : "1368699816215",
    "timestampUsec" : "1368699816215241",
    "id" : "tag:google.com,2005:reader/item/84c25c636b707078",
    "categories" : [ "user/17115776656148603551/state/com.google/read", "user/17115776656148603551/state/com.google/starred", "user/17115776656148603551/state/com.google/fresh", "Breakfast", "Gluten-Free", "Photo", "Pudding" ],
    "title" : "yogurt panna cotta with walnuts and honey",
    "published" : 1366988860,
    "updated" : 1366988860,
    "canonical" : [ {
      "href" : "http://smittenkitchen.com/blog/2013/04/yogurt-panna-cotta-with-walnuts-and-honey/"
    } ],
    "alternate" : [ {
      "href" : "http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/smittenkitchen/~3/t_w8asbkyNg/",
      "type" : "text/html"
    } ],
    "content" : {
      "direction" : "ltr",
      "content" : "<p><a href=\"http://smittenkitchen.com/blog/2013/04/yogurt-panna-cotta-with-walnuts-and-honey/\" title=\"yogurt panna cotta with walnuts and honey\"><img src=\"http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8400/8682467912_efaa762c89.jpg\" width=\"500\" height=\"333\" alt=\"yogurt panna cotta with walnuts and honey\"></a></p>\nGuys, I just discovered the ultimate weekend brunch treat/decadent dessert that still contains a whiff of moderation/<a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/smitten/8681658077/in/photostream\">preschooler</a> snack. The ingredient list is so short, and the cooking process is so simple that you’ll have the recipe memorized by the time you make it the second time. And you will make it a second time, maybe even within a week. It looks pretty, tastes luxurious and… well, most of you probably discovered panna cotta a decade ago.\n<p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/smitten/8682466230/\" title=\"lemon, gelatin, sugar, milk/cream, yogurt\"><img src=\"http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8395/8682466230_9e19d63848.jpg\" width=\"500\" height=\"333\" alt=\"lemon, gelatin, sugar, milk/cream, yogurt\"></a><br>\n<a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/smitten/8682466352/\" title=\"thick greek yogurt\"><img src=\"http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8262/8682466352_5a3120eb08.jpg\" width=\"500\" height=\"333\" alt=\"thick greek yogurt\"></a></p>\n<p>I’m sorry, I’m just slow. For example, this week I started reading <a href=\"http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1594483299/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&amp;camp=1789&amp;creative=390957&amp;creativeASIN=1594483299&amp;linkCode=as2&amp;tag=smitten-20\">this new book</a> that everyone was talking about in September … 2007. And that’s just the beginning. Gallery wall? Skinny jeans? Arrested Development? Quinoa? People, I am <i>on it</i>. True to sluggish form, it’s been a full four years since my friend Nicole gushed to me about the wonders of yogurt panna cotta. I put it on my cooking to-do list, blinked, and that about brings us up to last week when I saw it on my list and thought, “right, wasn’t I going to make that a few days ago?”</p>\n<p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/smitten/8681355169/\" title=\"yogurt whisked with milk or cream\"><img src=\"http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8522/8681355169_9657d4a377.jpg\" width=\"500\" height=\"333\" alt=\"yogurt whisked with milk or cream\"></a></p>\n<p><b>... Read the rest of <a href=\"http://smittenkitchen.com/blog/2013/04/yogurt-panna-cotta-with-walnuts-and-honey/\">yogurt panna cotta with walnuts and honey</a> on <a href=\"http://smittenkitchen.com\">smittenkitchen.com</a></b></p>\n<hr>\n<p><small>© smitten kitchen 2006-2012. |\n<a href=\"http://smittenkitchen.com/blog/2013/04/yogurt-panna-cotta-with-walnuts-and-honey/\">permalink to <b>yogurt panna cotta with walnuts and honey</b></a> | <a href=\"http://smittenkitchen.com/blog/2013/04/yogurt-panna-cotta-with-walnuts-and-honey/#comments\">220 comments</a> to date | see more: <a href=\"http://smittenkitchen.com/blog/category/breakfast/\" title=\"View all posts in Breakfast\" rel=\"category tag\">Breakfast</a>, <a href=\"http://smittenkitchen.com/blog/category/gluten-free/\" title=\"View all posts in Gluten-Free\" rel=\"category tag\">Gluten-Free</a>, <a href=\"http://smittenkitchen.com/blog/category/photo/\" title=\"View all posts in Photo\" rel=\"category tag\">Photo</a>, <a href=\"http://smittenkitchen.com/blog/category/pudding/\" title=\"View all posts in Pudding\" rel=\"category tag\">Pudding</a>\n</small></p>"
    },
    "author" : "deb",
    "comments" : [ ],
    "annotations" : [ ],
    "origin" : {
      "streamId" : "feed/http://feeds.feedburner.com/smittenkitchen",
      "title" : "smitten kitchen",
      "htmlUrl" : "http://smittenkitchen.com"
    }
  } ]
}


    $(document).ready(function() {


            var output='<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><title>Instapaper: Export</title></head><body><h1>Unread</h1><ol></ol><h1>Archive</h1><ol>';

                $.each(data.items, function(i, data){
                output+='<li><a href="'+ data['title'] + '">'+ data['title'] + data['canonical'].href + '</li>:';
                });   

            output+='</ol></body></html>';
            document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
    });

        </script>
```

Comment: We are going to need how `STARRED>JSON CONTENT GOES HERE` look like, otherwise we can't help you..

Comment: @TryingToImprove added content of starred.json

Comment: Well, for starters, there's a wrong closing quote in that long "content" field. It's where it says `click/1594483299">this new book`, it should be `click/1594483299\">this new book`. I don't know if that's the problem.

Comment: @Aioros no thats not the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the properties you need with:

```
var title = data.title,
    url = data.canonical[0].href,
    summary = data.summary.content;
```

Alternatively you can use 'this' instead of 'data' which may make the code easier to follow given that 'data' is used differently elsewhere.

Comment: This is probably the right solution, I only think you should change `this` with `data`, just for clarity, since that's the name being used in the question.

Comment: @RobJ I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Comment: There are syntax errors in the JSON itself. If you are using an IDE it should highlight the errors for you. Look for unescaped quotes and so on (see comment from Aioros below your question). That should fix any issues. Also if displaying on screen you should filter the summaries to ensure they do not contain any unwelcome script tags and so on.

Comment: @Robj I think its got to do with the dataType

Comment: Using the snippet of code you've posted above, it works fine for me once I've made the changes in my answer and escaped the rogue quote that Aioros pointed out. Does the code you've posted accurately represent how you are getting the json into the script or are you fetching it from an external file? If so, have you remembered to parse the json? var data = JSON.parse(jsonString);